# ProgressBar in Actionbar displays text instead of the layout file

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-progressbar, android-menu

I followed this [tutorial](http://blog.clockworkbits.com/2014/04/11/progress-bar-in-the-actionbar/) to put a `ProgressBar` in the action bar. But instead of showing the progress bar, it shows the menu item's title "working". I have removed the text ***working*** and then nothing appears. I only want the progress bar to display.

***Can anyone help me understand what I did wrong?***

Before being pressed:

[image]

During the 'refresh' stage when the progress bar should be shown.

[image]

Here is my layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             style="@android:style/Widget.ActionButton"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:focusable="false"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Here is my Menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/master_refresh_action"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_refresh"
        android:title="Refresh"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/pb_master_refresh"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/refresh_menuitem"
        android:title="working"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

And the code from my Activity:

```
    //USED FOR MENU ITEM REFRESH
    private static final int STATE_IDLE = 0;
    private static final int STATE_WORKING = 1;
    private int mState;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_master);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.masterToolBar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        ab = getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        ab.setTitle("Loading");

        mState = STATE_IDLE;

    }


@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_master, menu);
       // itemBtnRefresh = menu.findItem(R.id.master_refresh_action);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.master_refresh_action:
                refreshData();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuItem refresh = menu.findItem(R.id.master_refresh_action);
        MenuItem progressBar = menu.findItem(R.id.pb_master_refresh);

        switch (mState) {
            case STATE_IDLE:
                refresh.setVisible(true);
                progressBar.setVisible(false);
                break;
            case STATE_WORKING:
                refresh.setVisible(false);
                progressBar.setVisible(true);
                break;
            default: // Should never happen!
                refresh.setVisible(true);
                progressBar.setVisible(false);
                break;
        }

        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }



       private void setState(int state) {
            mState = state;
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }


    private SomeAsyncTask <>{

    OnPreExecute{
    setState(STATE_WORKING);
    }

    OnPostExecute{
    setState(STATE_IDLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to remove title?

Comment: Yes, I get the error "Menu Items should display a title"

Answer (score -1):

try to use always in action it will force action bar to display it.

```
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/master_refresh_action"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_refresh"
        android:title="Refresh"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/pb_master_refresh"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/refresh_menuitem"
        android:title=""
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: I only want the progress bar to be displayed with no title.

Comment: ... Not sure why you are wanting me to hide the refresh icon.... that part works. The issue is when the pb_master_refresh layout is displayed, its like its not getting inflated.

Comment: put ifRoom for refresh and check.

Comment: Yeah neither of your suggestions have helped. Thanks though!